# prevent/force execution of Gtk3 accelerators

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, accelerator

I've recently decided to write my first Gtk3 app, and I'm having trouble with accelerators. I know how to add accelerators, but they just refuse to work with certain keys, like rightarrow and leftarrow. This is a simple program which should (but doesn't) destroy the GtkWindow when rightarrow is pressed. It works with most other buttons, though.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
keyval= 65363

w=Gtk.Window()
menubar= Gtk.MenuBar()
filemenu= Gtk.Menu()
accels= Gtk.AccelGroup()
w.add_accel_group(accels)
file= Gtk.MenuItem.new_with_mnemonic('_File')
new= Gtk.ImageMenuItem.new_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_NEW, None)
new.add_accelerator('activate', accels, keyval, Gdk.ModifierType(0), Gtk.AccelFlags(1))
file.set_submenu(filemenu)
filemenu.append(new)
new.connect('activate', lambda a: w.destroy())
menubar.append(file)
w.add(menubar)
w.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Then, on the other hand, there's another problem: if a widget has the keyboard focus (e.g. a GtkEntry) and an accelerator key combination is pressed, the accelerator action is executed - but the widget doesn't receive the key press. Is there a way to prevent this other than removing the AccelGroup from the window whenever a widget is focused?

Comment: It's possible that gtk3 does not allow arrows as accels. I have read elsewhere that it wasn't allowed with gtk2. Back then the answer was it had something to do with arrows being used for widget focus.